# Determine specific integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I wanted to determine a specific integral, but my solution is always different from the value Wolfram Alpha gives me.
Given $f(x) = (1-|x|)_+$ and I want to calculate $\int e^{itx} f(x) ~dx$. 
I interpreted $f$ as the maximum value function, i.e. $f(x) = max\{1-|x|,0\}$

$$\int e^{itx} (1-|x|)_+ ~dx = \int_{-1}^1 e^{itx} (1-|x|) ~dx $$
By integration by parts $\left( u(x) = 1-|x| \rightarrow u'(x) = -\frac{x}{|x|}, ~v'(x) = e^{itx} \rightarrow v(x) = \frac{1}{it}e^{itx} \right) $
$$\left[(1-|x|) \frac{1}{it} e^{itx} \right]_{-1}^1 - \int_{-1}^1 -\frac{x}{|x|}\frac{1}{it} e^{itx} dx = \frac{1}{it} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{|x|} e^{itx} dx$$
Now integrate by parts again $\left( u(x) = \frac{x}{|x|} \rightarrow u'(x) = 0,~v'(x) = e^{itx} \rightarrow v(x) = \frac{1}{it}e^{itx} \right)$
and in the end i get $$-\frac{1}{t^2} \left(e^{it} + e^{-it} \right) = - \frac{\cos t}{t^2}$$
But Wolfram Alpha says it has to be $$- \frac{e^{-it} (-1 + e^{it})^2}{t^2} = \frac{2-2 \cos t}{t^2}$$

So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not really differentiable, so your integration by parts is a bit non-rigorous (and as far as I can see non-working (but you might be able to fix that using distributions)). I would suggest that you instead use parity first, to write your integral as
$$
2\int_0^1 (1-x)\cos tx\,dx.
$$
Then continue with the integration by parts, and you will readily get
$$
\frac{2-2\cos t}{t^2}
$$
just as Wolfram Alpha (which is, in this case, correct).

Comment: Why did you write your integral as $2 \int_0^1 (1-x) \cos tx dx$? By Euler's formula you have $e^{itx} = \cos tx + i \sin tx$ ... But I do unterstand the last few steps (integration by parts).

Comment: The functions $x\mapsto (1-|x|)_+$ and $x\mapsto \sin tx$ are even and odd, respectively, so the integral of their product equals $0$. For the cosine term, you get double the integral from $0$ to $1$ instead, since that part is even.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @mickep's nice solution is to divide the integral into positive and negative parts as follows

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 e^{itx} (1-|x|) ~dx
&=\int_{-1}^0 e^{itx} (1+x) ~dx+\int_{0}^1 e^{itx} (1-x) ~dx\\
&=\int_{0}^1 e^{-itx} (1-x) ~dx+\int_{0}^1 e^{itx} (1-x) ~dx\\
&=2\int_{0}^1  (1-x)\cos tx ~dx
\end{align}
$$